# If motion is relative, can we say that the Earth doesn't revolve around the Sun?

Tags: reference-frames, orbital-motion, inertial-frames, relative-motion, solar-system

Considering motion to be relative, consider these two cases as follows

> 1. An observer is standing on the sun and observing the earth and the earth has no background (no stars and stuff in the background). The observer notices the earth to be rotating and the sun to be stationary.
>    So the observer on sun might make the statement: "Earth doesn't revolve but **rotates** and the sun is stationary"

> 2. Another observer is standing on the earth and might notice that the earth is not rotating but is revolving around the sun.
>    So the observer on earth might make the statement: "Earth **revolves** and the sun is stationary".

So, can we say the different statements made by the two observers are both true from their own frame of reference?

Comment: Possible duplicates: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/10933/2451 , https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/66476/2451 and links therein.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why do we say that the Earth moves around the Sun?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/10933/)